# Is it OK to define an opaque type as an empty struct to get around linker warning in C++/CLI?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a C++ project that is configured to use CLR. The project contains a subclass of `CTreeCtrl`, i.e. a class provided by Microsoft that I have no control over. Since the public interface of `CTreeCtrl` heavily uses the type `HTREEITEM`, it is unavoidable that the subclass also makes use of the type - but since the type is "opaque", the subclass only passes around `HTREEITEM` references without actually doing anything with the referenced objects.

By "opaque", I mean that `HTREEITEM` is only visible as a forward-declared type. Here's the declaration that I see in `CommCtrl.h`:

```
struct _TREEITEM;
typedef struct _TREEITEM *HTREEITEM;
```

Unfortunately, in a release build this usage of `HTREEITEM` generates the following linker warning:

```
foo.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (01000017) for '_TREEITEM'; image may not run
```

[Here is the MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8027ys9.aspx) for the warning. I have searched the net for a solution to get rid of the warning, but have found nothing - only confirmation that over the years other people have encountered this warning in relation to `HTREEITEM` as well.

Now I have been thinking of a workaround myself. Given that

- My class only gets `HTREEITEM`  references from `CtreeCtrl` and passes them back to `CtreeCtrl`, without any kind of interpretation or function calls
- `HTREEITEM` is merely a pointer to `_TREEITEM`

It follows that all that my class ever does is pass around pointers to `_TREEITEM`. My idea for a workaround therefore is this: Why not define `_TREEITEM` as an empty struct in my project, like this:

```
struct _TREEITEM
{
};
```

Obviously this makes the linker happy since it now sees the complete type. The fact that the struct definition is incorrect is not relevant since my class is only passing around pointers to `_TREEITEM`, i.e. all that the compiler needs to know is the size of a `HTREEITEM`.

I have tried this workaround and it seems to work, not only at compile time but at runtime as well. So what do you think of this workaround? Did I overlook something? I certainly won't be offended if you call it an ugly hack :-)

FWIW: I am currently on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I would prefer to leave the type undefined and just tolerate the warning.  "The linker will provide the native type definition in the MSIL metadata" sounds good to me.

Comment: @aschepler Except that I'm trying to adopt a "warnings = errors" policy in my team. It's harsh, I know, but over the years some real errors have made it into the software because nobody paid any attention to warnings.